# send velocity command to wheels of pioneer3at in standalone version of gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I installed standalone version of gazebo and i put a pioneer3at robot with laser scanner in environment, now i can get data of laser in my code but i don't know how can i send command to robot for moving in my code, i am new in gazebo and i want to test my navigation algorithm in simulated pioneer3at robot. i don't want to use ros, just i want to work with standalone version of gazebo, any one can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2772/send-velocity-command-to-wheels-of-pioneer3at-in-standalone-version-of-gazebo/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try and use the [SkidSteerDrivePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/SkidSteerDrivePlugin.cc) to drive a pioneer3at.

Looking at the source code, it expects you to publish a pose msg to `~/your_model_name_here/vel_cmd` topic

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-15**:
Sending a Pose msg to a vel_cmd topic just seems wrong..

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-16**:
why is it wrong? i want to test my navigation algorithm so i should can control the robot, so i think it is correct . if it is possible explain more about my wrong?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-16**:
A twist message seems more appropriate for a "velocity command" topic.. maybe these messages don't exist as yet?

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-24**:
yes, you are right, twist message is not exist, just pose message is exist for "velocity command" topic.